How to show only downloaded map tiles and not the default Apple/Google maps with MapView library in Expo/React-Native
I am displaying a map view in my react native app like this, using the MapView library.
<View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView region={region} style={styles.map}>
        <UrlTile urlTemplate={dir}></UrlTile>
    </MapView>
</View>

I have open street maps tiles saved locally in the documents directory of the filesystem and I am loading it into the app as a Url tile. The dir variable is defined like this
const dir = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'public/maps/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
The issue I am having is that MapView only puts my downloaded tile on top of the default Apple maps  and if I zoom out or leave the region in which I have the downloaded tiles it show the default map. Also when I zoom in or out on the downloaded tiles, it flickers and I can briefly see the default map.
What I want do do is to only show the downloaded tiles from open street maps and to restrict the map view to the region in which I have downloaded the tiles for.
I am stuck here and I would appreciate if anyone here know how to approach this issue.

import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { UrlTile } from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default function App() {
  const dir = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'public/maps/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'; // Define the directory for locally stored map tiles

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView region={region} style={styles.map}>
        <UrlTile
          urlTemplate={dir}
          shouldReplaceMapContent={true}
          maximumZ={MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL}
          minimumZ={MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL}
        />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}


I figured out how to remove the default google/apple map and only show the downloaded tiles. I just added the shouldReplaceMapContent={true} property to the UrlTile component. LocalTile doesn't work in this case because it considers the mobile file path to be a url. The map still flickers when zooming in and out, I will leave an update when I figure it out. Thank you for your reponse.

@anonymous2343 you might try optimizing the rendering of the tiles. One approach could be to preload the tiles for the current zoom level and the adjacent zoom levels. This can help ensure a smoother experience when zooming in and out. Check my updated code.
